# issues installing gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1' on Mac OSX 10.8.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, bundler

Trying to troubleshoot a web app and in doing so I am going through the steps in http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Rails_3.  I am stuck on trying to get the console to run. It asks me to bundle and then when I get an error for bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'. This is the error i get when i try to use gem install:

```
gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bcrypt-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
xcrun cc -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   -c bcrypt_ext.c
xcrun: Error: failed to exec real xcrun. (No such file or directory)
xcrun cc -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   -c crypt.c
xcrun: Error: failed to exec real xcrun. (No such file or directory)
xcrun cc -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   -c crypt_blowfish.c
xcrun: Error: failed to exec real xcrun. (No such file or directory)
xcrun cc -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   -c crypt_gensalt.c
xcrun: Error: failed to exec real xcrun. (No such file or directory)
xcrun cc -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   -c wrapper.c
xcrun: Error: failed to exec real xcrun. (No such file or directory)
cc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -o bcrypt_ext.bundle bcrypt_ext.o crypt.o crypt_blowfish.o crypt_gensalt.o wrapper.o -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64     -lruby  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'bcrypt_ext.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'crypt.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'crypt_blowfish.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'crypt_gensalt.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'wrapper.o'
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/karrde00/.gems/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/karrde00/.gems/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Do you have the Xcode command line tools installed?

Comment: how is this RVM related?

Comment: Yes I have xcode CLI installed. And I brought up RVM as I use it to manage ruby versions